# Installing cvxopt on windows 8 using anaconda and python 3.4

Tags: windows-8, python-3.4, conda, cvxopt

Has anyone managed to successfully install cvxopt on a windows 8 machine, using the anaconda distribution package with python 3.4?

I have tried both conda install cvxopt and pip install and both fail.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: try this http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt

Comment: After spending a fair amount of time, the following seems to work:                 conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/omnia cvxopt

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: That was `conda install -c omnia cvxopt` for me

Comment: Note: `conda install -c omnia cvxopt` doesn't work in python 3.5; you need to downgrade to 3.4 first.